# Versioning in Apple On Demand Resources

Tags: ios, app-store, on-demand-resources

I am a service within a third party native application and fall under the Apple TOS subject where all of the HTML content needs to be embedded into the application. Hence we are providing all of our files to application owner and they distribute it.

Content distributed via web has no problem with versioning, but having old versions of our service running in some iOS application is not great as we'd need to ensure backwards compatibility for this.

I've been looking into alternative options (if there are any) and found that Apple has ODR (On Demand Resources). The docs aren't great and I can't really find my answer to few simple questions:

1. How are the resources in ODR updated? Can they be updated independently to the application itself and if they are updated then old versions of application would re-download them? Meaning that if i'm updating the software independent to the application, can I distribute those changes to old applications as well?
2. If application version changes, but resources in ODR remain the same, will it continue to work (basically vice versa to #1)?
3. Can I separate my service in a separate ODR and manage it independently?